Interpreting RAM diagnostic results (E-mu Emax 2 digital sampling keyboard)
I have a broken E-mu Emax 2 digital sampling keyboard (1989). I ran the unit's internal diagnostic but need help interpreting the results, which indicate a faulty DRAM chip (KM44C256BP-8, of which there are many).
Its internal diagnostic reports that address 400000 has a value of D575 that should be a value of 5678.
The diagnostic manual explains how to use this information to identify the bad IC# by "first determining which bit is bad (convert Hex-to-binary) and then swapping the chip corresponding to that bit." It then provides a "Memory Troubleshooting Chart" that seems to cross-reference bit range to IC#. (See attached image)
I am at a loss to understand which number (400000? D575? 5678?) I am supposed to convert from hex-to-binary, then at a loss as to how to use the resulting binary to find the bad IC# using the chart. Fwiw, my best guess was to convert the address 400000 to binary (010000000000000000000000), but not clear how that number then relates to the bit ranges on the Troubleshooting Chart.
Thanks in advance for any ideas or answers you can provide

The 400000 defines the memory address where the error is - on motherboard or expansion board, and it ties the problem to four chips that are at that address and store the 16-bit data value.
The stored data should be 5678 but when the CPU tried to write that and read it back, it got a garbage value of D575. So you have six bits flipped incorrectly spread over 3 chips, which indicates that only 1 chip out of 4 for that address returned a correct bit pattern.
Which may be a coincidence.
What you just saw is the CPU not being able to read back what it wrote.
It does not mean the memory chips are broken. It may mean something else prevents them from functioning correctly.
Unfortunately there is no indication to which area the 400000h points to - other that it is the first address at 4 megabyte mark.
So do not just start randomly swapping DRAM chips, the problem is likely something else that applies to the whole device, whole memory, or just a badly seated memory expansion card.

Thank you so much for taking the time to look at this and respond. I've read your response over and over and some of it is starting to make sense (as I've been bingeing on YT videos trying to understand how RAM works). So, the table (see image) doesn't offer any clues as to which chips are involved? I will double check traces, power (dmm shows good voltage, but i'll scope it for ripples), ground and proper seating. Doesn't seem there's a good way to test RAM with a DMM or scope, unfortunately.
